# Copying parts of a pandas column to other parts of the same column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following Pandas df:

```
          Var_1  Var_2  
-----------------------
12/11/13    0      0         
12/18/13    0      0       
12/25/13    0      0       
01/01/13    1      3        
01/08/14    2      4       
01/15/14    3      2       
01/22/14    4      1       
01/29/14    5      0
```

I want to change it to:

```
          Var_1  Var_2  
-----------------------
12/11/13    3      0         
12/18/13    4      0       
12/25/13    5      0       
01/01/13    1      3        
01/08/14    2      4       
01/15/14    3      2       
01/22/14    4      1       
01/29/14    5      0
```

I tried to copy the values inplace by doing:

```
df['Var_1'].iloc[:3] = df['Var_1'].iloc[4:]
```

But I get:

```
          Var_1  Var_2  
-----------------------
12/11/13   NaN     0         
12/18/13   NaN     0       
12/25/13   NaN     0       
01/01/13    1      3        
01/08/14    2      4       
01/15/14    3      2       
01/22/14    4      1       
01/29/14    5      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df['Var_1'].iloc[:3] = df['Var_1'].iloc[5:].tolist()
```

Two things: slice indexing starts at the index you provide- so: `4:` is index `4` inclusive.

Secondly - think about it that way - you were trying to replace part of your `pd.Series` with another `pd.Series`. If you mean simple values insert, without retaining indexes, or group by or anything else - it's safe call to just convert it to list. Try e.g.

```py
df['Var_1'].iloc[:5] = df['Var_2'].iloc[:5]
```

It will work because index is retained and size matches.